# Why the view provided by onViewCreated() works as non null for one method and as null for the other method?

Tags: java, android, view, nullpointerexception

Why the view provided by onViewCreated() works as non null in simple findViews(View view) but for the other method which is for OnWindowFocusChangeListener(...) throws NullPointerException?

I have no idea what to do to solve this problem. I mean, I have no idea what to try.

'''

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        findViews(view);

        .....................................

        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnWindowFocusChangeListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onWindowFocusChanged(final boolean hasFocus) {
                actionsForUISizesOptimizationProcess(hasFocus,view);
            }
        });
    }


void actionsForUISizesOptimizationProcess(boolean hasFocus, View view){
        FrameLayout fragmentContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer); //debugging showed that the view in this line is null

        int displayWidth = fragmentContainer.getWidth(); //java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.FrameLayout.getWidth()' on a null object reference
        int displayHeight = fragmentContainer.getHeight();

        ...........................................
    }
```

'''

[image]

Comment: I think the view is `null` because in the `onViewCreated` method you only setup the `AddOnWindowsFocusChangeListener`. Once this listener is actually executed the view is out of scope therefore `null`.

What you could try is to save the view as an `final` instance but this is maybe a architecture smell.

Comment: @BrunoBieri if you look at the code, the parameter `view` is already defined as `final`, so it isn't "out of scope". However, that isn't OP's problem.

Comment: @DavidWasser you're totally right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view` is not `null`. The problem is this code in `actionsForUISizesOptimizationProcess()`:

```
fragmentContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
```

`fragmentContainer` is null. The call to `findViewById()` is returning `null`

So, maybe there is no `View` with ID `fragmentContainer` in the `View` hierarchy?

Comment: I didn't think that this bug has so simple solution. OMG. The stupid think was - I thought that view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnWindowFocusChangeListener(...)  works with Activity-s layout. Ehhh... Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In your xml file, check if the id of your **FrameLayout** is `fragmentContainer` and there exists `no typo`

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a a typo in your XML file where the id is supposed to be fragmentContainer which is why the findViewById() is not finding it.